# Make a html to pdf converter

Tags: html, pdf, converters

I am pretty new to developing softwares and am intrigued by the huge world out there!! I have working knowledge of C/C++ and Java.. I was thinking of making an application that would convert a webpage to a pdf document.. I know there are many solutions available -- both online and offline..But I want to develop my own.. I googled but couldn't find anything that would help me get started..
I want to know how do we go about a conversion process?? How to get started?? What languages and technologies are pre-requisites for making a converter like this??

Thank You

Comment: I will suggest not reinvent the wheel, search the libraries in your favorite language and start playing with it. Also please clarify what **webpages** your are going to use either arbitrary from internet or create your own for easy editing?

Comment: @Asad Rasheed The application should be able to convert any arbitrary page into a pdf file.. So will using java be easier for a project of this kind??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at least you need to get to the bottom to following specifications:

1. [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)
2. [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/)
3. [JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)
4. [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)

Moreover here are a lot of minor stuff such as Fonts, Decription/Encription algorithms and many many other minor but still necessary things.

I think you can imagine that this is quite a long way to get all this working. In fact, the complexity of such software is the reason why so many companies make money in this field.

Anyway, I'd suggest you to start from the simple things and grow your software gradually. Start with converting HTML to Image, because it is a bit simpler. Take and parse HTML, its CSS, its JavaScript. Clean HTML. Build DOM of the HTML document. Apply styles. Go thru the DOM and draw elements to the image.

Good luck!